# How to create a better (more userfriendly) admin interface for non-technical "admin user"?

Tags: 7, users, theming

I'm trying to make Drupal admin interface easier for non-technical users.

Actually, I'm trying to "create" a **new** interface for these kind of users. I'm using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) etc. to make a better admin interface experience without scaring them with a complex structure.

### Easily;

- edit, enable/disable blocks,
- edit-rearrange main menu,
- manage users,
- manage contents,
- manage files, images etc. uploaded via Drupal interface,

#### What should be done to increase user experience of this admin interface?

Is there any must-use module you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use this myself as I prefer the slimer [Administration Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu), but I think [Navbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/navbar) is more newbie friendly

[image]